# Error in exporting highchart while using allowHTML and useHTMl

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts, angular5

I have set `useHTML` and `allowHTML` to true in Highchart. In the view the html is rendered properly but while exporting the chart using `exportChartLocal()` the highchart throws the error : `'Image type not supported for charts with embedded HTML'` . What might be the cause for it is there any other way to achieve the same thing in export too?
The code snippet is below:

```js
this.chart.exportChartLocal({
type:'application/pdf',
filname: 'chart'
})

subtitle:{
useHTML: true,
text: 'part1 &nbsp; - &nbsp; xyz
  <br> p2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp; zzz
<br> pp3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp; dd',
style:{ fontSize:10px}
}

exporting{
enabled: false,
allowHTML: true,
fallbackToExportServer: false,
error: (options,err){
console.log(err)
}
}
```

Comment: The error says it all. The further explanation can be found under the error #28 section (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/28/) which can be received upon exporting chart (https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z4d85a0o/) to any format (check the browser's console for the link). In a nutshell, you cannot export chart without fall backing to export server when a chart contains HTML elements while they are allowed (allowHTML: true). The solution for this problem would be to set up your own server and not using the offline module at all. This way you wouldn't send any data to our server.